# Storing DOUBLE vs INT --> Query time and Ingest time

Tags: types, google-bigquery

I have a column that is of numeric type. I'm not sure whether it will be a whole number or a decimal number. There are two options here:

1. I can store the numbers as a DOUBLE whether it's whole or decimal.
2. I can infer the type and store the numbers as a DOUBLE if it's a decimal or INT if it's whole.

My question then is, it is much simpler to store it as a DOUBLE (because an int can just be represented as "5.0"), so what's the difference in Ingest time and query time if something is stored as a double vs an int. How 'expensive' is it to incorrectly store the type of an INT as a DOUBLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [BigQuery pricing table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data), both integers and floating point numbers use 8 bytes, so actual cost will be the same.

The [BigQuery floating point type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#floating-point-type) is 64 bits. (I believe DOUBLE, FLOAT, and FLOAT64 are [synonyms, based on the REST docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#schema.fields.type))

Comment: I'm not concerned with pricing here -- I'm more concerned about performance hits on querying or ingesting a DOUBLE vs an INT.

Comment: How compressible your data is will have the biggest effect on query performance, regardless of data type. I wouldn't imagine there being much of a difference if you are storing integers as floats, but I haven't run a performance test on it.